# Recursivity in Javascript and JSON

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm writing an app that need parse a Json file with a arbitrary content using Angular and Angular UI Bootstrap.

Each root node of Json file will be rendered as a tab and content of each tab will be created with a recursive function traversing the node.

But I can't figure why the node is not traversing completely.

In first node ("conceitos"), all content is rendered.

But in second and third node ("nascimento", "historico") the contend is rendered partially

In the following nodes the browser crashes
EDITED: Don't crashes anymore. I think was a something in my browser.

This snippet show this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Recursivity Test</title>
<link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
</head>

<body>
<div ng-app="governanca" ng-controller="governanca">
  <uib-tabset active="abaAtiva">
    <uib-tab ng-repeat="item in content" index="$index" heading="{{item.key}}" select="carregacontent($index)"><div ng-bind-html="$parent.contentAtual"></div></uib-tab>
  </uib-tabset>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.8.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var app = angular.module("governanca", ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngSanitize']);
app.controller("governanca", ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){
 var arquivo = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/viniciusosousa/governancaCorporativa/master/governancaCorporativa.json";
 $scope.contentAtual = '';
 $scope.abaAtiva = 0;
 $http.get(arquivo)
 .then(function(response){
  $scope.content = d3.entries(response.data);
 });

 $scope.carregacontent = function(index){
  self.HTML = '';
  console.log('***********************   NODE ITEM *************************');
  console.log(angular.toJson($scope.content[index].value,true));
  console.log('***********************   NODE END *************************');
  $scope.contentAtual = processContent($scope.content[index].value);
} 
 
  function processContent(item){
  if( typeof item == "object"){
  if( Object.prototype.toString.call( item ) === '[object Array]' || (item.hasOwnProperty('key') && item.hasOwnProperty('value')) ) {
   content = item;
  } else {
   content = d3.entries(item);
  }
  
   for (i=0; i < content.length; i++){
   if (content[i].hasOwnProperty('value')){
    self.HTML += '<h3>'+content[i].key+'</h3>'
    itemcontent = content[i].value 
   }  else {
    itemcontent = content[i];
     }
     processContent(itemcontent);
   }

  } else {
   self.HTML += item+'<br/>';
  }
   return self.HTML;
 };
 
}]);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

My JSON file

[JSON file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/viniciusosousa/governancaCorporativa/master/governancaCorporativa.json)

Comment: Why do you call `processContent(itemcontent)` within `for` loop? Can you include input `JSON` or JavaScript object at Question?

Comment: `the browser crashes` - in what way?

Comment: *"Each root node"* - By definition, wouldn't there be only one root node? Please [edit] your question to show an example of your JSON input.

Comment: My Json file https://raw.githubusercontent.com/viniciusosousa/governancaCorporativa/master/governancaCorporativa.json

Comment: @nnnnnn Sorry for this. I want say the nodes immediately after the root node